# move command performs move in source directory too

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have written a shell script to move files from source directory to destination directory.

`/home/tmp/ to /home/from/`

The move happens correctly but it displays message

```
mv: /home/tmp/testfile_retry_17072017.TIF
/home/tmp/testfile_retry_17072017.TIF are identical.
```

and if source directory is empty it displays

```
mv: cannot rename /home/tmp/* to /home/from/*
```

for file in `/home/tmp/*`

```
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    do 
        DIRPATH=$(dirname "${file}")
        FILENAME=$(basename "${file}")
#       echo "Dirpath = ${DIRPATH} Filename = ${FILENAME}"
        mv "${DIRPATH}/"${FILENAME} /home/from
        echo ${FILENAME} " moved to from directory" 
    done
else
    echo "Directory is empty"
fi
```

Comment: Why not just do `mv $file /home/from`?  `$DIRPATH/$FILENAME` is the same as `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

You have things a bit out of order with:

```
for file in /home/tmp/*
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    do
```

Of course `"$file"` will exist -- you are looping `for file in /home/tmp/*`. It looks like you intended

```
for file in /home/tmp/*
do
    FILENAME=$(basename "${file}")
    if [ ! -f "/home/from/$FILENAME" ]  ## if it doesn't already exist in dest
    then
```

Note: POSIX shell include *parameter expansions* that allow you to avoid calling `dirname` and `basename`. Instead you can simply use `"${file##*/}"` for the filename (which just says remove everything from the *left* up to (and including) the last `/`). That is the only expansion you need (as you already know the destination directory name). This allows you to check `[ -f "$dest/${f##*/}" ]` to determine if a file with the same name you are moving already exists in `/home/from`

You could use that to your advantage with:

```
src=/home/tmp           ## source dir
dst=/home/from          ## destination dir

for f in "$src"/*       ## for each file in src
do
    [ "$f" = "$src/*" ] && break  ## src is empty
    if [ -f "$dst/${f##*/}" ]   ## test if it already exists in dst
    then
        printf "file '%s' exists in '%s' - forcing mv.\n" "${f##*/}" "$dst"
        mv -f "$f" "$dst"       ## use -f to overwrite existing
    else
        mv "$f" "$dst"          ## regular move otherwise
    fi
done
```

There is a great resource for checking your shell code called [**ShellCheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/). Just type your code into the webpage (or paste it) and it will analyze your logic and variable use and let you know where problem are identified.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your suggestion. My concern is not about file existing in destination. It's that files do not exists in source directory. The script run at regular intervals and there are times when there are no files in source directory.

Comment: @asmitathakur - I added a check to catch the empty source directory and simply exit the loop with `break` in that event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use find instead of /home/tmp/* as shown.

```
for file in $(find /home/tmp/ -type f)
do
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
        DIRPATH=$(dirname "${file}")
        FILENAME=$(basename "${file}")
#       echo "Dirpath = ${DIRPATH} Filename = ${FILENAME}"
        mv "${DIRPATH}/"${FILENAME} /home/from
        echo ${FILENAME} " moved to from directory" 
else
    echo "Directory is empty"
fi

done
```

Comment: Still getting same messages

Comment: I suppose you have a filename in /tmp directory by the name  '*' . remove that file. its should work.

Comment: There is no such file. even if the directory is empty the code considers * as a file name and doesn't seem to go in else block

Comment: empty directories will not be part of find  "/home/tmp/ -type f "  output. There is some information that's missing here.